# Check if a string matches a regex and strip a part of it out for use

Tags: ruby, regex, url

I want to add an automatic embedding feature when a YouTube URL is used (`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VID`, where VID is the video's ID).

For this, I need to check if the given URL, stored in the variable `url`, matches "`/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9]+).*/i`", then I need to strip out the VID to use it (e.g. put the VID in another variable).

How can I do this (both matching and stripping)? Thanks.

---

P.S. Yes, I will take care of video's where embedding is disabled.
P.P.S. No, not that kind of stripping!

Comment: YouTube now has upcase characters in their video id. You may want to include [A-Z] somewhere in your regex.

Comment: true, I didn't see that last time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just use the match String method with your regex, it will put the VID in the $1 variable if a match was found.

```
yourstring.match(/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9]+).*/i)
yourvariable = $1
```

Comment: I would prefer an `if`.  `if yourstring =~ /myregex(...)/; yourvar = $1; end`  Every time you compare or use a regex, it will populate the `$x` globals.  That means using `match` or `=~` or `!~` or other regex compare methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using `match` is Python-way. So use instead:

```
var = str[/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9]+).*/i,1]
```

or

```
/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(?<var>[a-z0-9]+).*/i =~ str
```